# Why is OS X using my 32px@2x icon instead of scaling down the 128px icon?

Tags: icon, mac, osx

I'm making a custom folder icon similar to the ones in the Home folder (Pictures, Documents, etc).

To do so, I extracted the images from the .icns of the blank folder icon and photoshopped my own graphic onto them. I followed Apple's [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-SW2) for icon sizing. I then packaged all the images into an .icns using Terminal.

**Now here's the problem:** When I put my icon next to one of the home folder icons (with icon size set at 64 x 64 in Finder), it doesn't match. For my icon, OS X is displaying the 32@2x icon. But for its own icons, OS X is displaying a scaled down 128px icon. If I re-export my custom icns *without* the 32@2x size (so OS X is forced to use the 128 instead), it looks fine.

Here is a screenshot. The difference between 32@2x and 128 scaled down is subtle but definitely there.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why OSX is doing that but I can say that "icon without 32@2x" looks worse to my eye. Too soft.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's fairly hard to diagnose — Icon Composer doesn't handle @2x icons. Are you viewing on a Retina Mac or non-Retina Mac?

Comment: @plainclothes I agree, but I'd prefer it not stick out like a sore thumb. "Without 32@2x" looks the same as the default icons.

Comment: @MarcEdwards Non-retina

Comment: Doesn't 32@2x mean that the image is actually 64 pixels? AFAIK, the 2x means "double pixel dimensions" and is used for double density displays. Note that the designation is a *naming* scheme and has no bearing at all with respect the actual data. (the table in the link clearly states this ["icon_32x32@2x -> 64x64"])

Comment: @horatio That is correct. But the .icns file for the system folders also contains a 64x64px icon. And yet OS X is displaying a scaled down 128px icon instead of using the 64px icon - but only for the default folders and not for my custom one.

Comment: so basically, you are saying that OSX is using 128px icons for everything including system items, *despite* the 64px setting *except* when a custom 64px file named "32@2x" exists for that item?

Comment: That is what appears to be happening

Comment: Have you tried Icon Slate? http://www.kodlian.com/apps It seems to handle 2x (I have it here), but I haven't tried making icons with @2x resources yet.